# migration of two models in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i wanna pass two models to a view .
and fill both fields of these tables , there.

is it correct?

```
    // public ActionResult checkout(string usernam)
    //{
       // ViewBag.username = usernam;
      //using(  var db=new myProjectContext())
      //{
        //  var tuple = new Tuple<tbl_Order, tbl_purchase>(new tbl_Order(),new tbl_purchase());

       // return View(tuple);
     // }
   // }



    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult checkout(string usernam)
    {
        ViewBag.username = usernam;

        var FeacherToTwoModel = new ViewModelX() ;

        return View(FeacherToTwoModel);

    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult checkout(ViewModelX model)
    {


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {


         UsersClass.InsertInOrderAndBasket(model.tbl_order.id, model.tbl_ order.id_Type,  model.tbl_ order.username,model.tbl_basket.username, model.tbl_basket.id_order);
        }
        else
        {

        }
        return View();

    }
```

and in view :

```
  //  @model Tuple<myProject.Models.tbl_Order, myProject.Models.tbl_purchase>
    //<label class="checkbox payment-method inline">
   // @Html.CheckBoxFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.TypeCheck)remember me</label>
     // .
     // .//other fields
     // .


       .
       .
       .
      <div id="collapseFour" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
      @model MyProject.Models.ViewModelX
      <p>please select a style</p>
      <label class="checkbox payment-method inline">

      @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.  )remember me </label>
     <label class="checkbox payment-method inline">
     @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m. )
     online
     </label>
                        <form class="form-inline">
                            <input class="input-block span4" placeholder="Enter your coupon code here" type="text" id="couponcode">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-general">register</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
      .
      .
      .

                            <tbody>
                            @model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.vw_basket>
                                @foreach (var item in Model)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="image"><a href='../Kala/Product?NID=@item.id_kala'>
                                            <img '@item.comment' alt='@item.name_product'  src="~/Content/Media/Images/product/@MyProject.Models.ProductClass.GetPicById_Product(int.Parse(item.id_Product.ToString()))" width="100"></a></td>
                                        <td class="product"><a href='../Kala/Product?NID=@item.id_ Product ' title='@item.comment'>@item.name_ Product </a> </td>
                                        <td class="stock">@item.number</td>
                                        <td class="price"><s></s> <b>@item.cost </b></td>
                                        <td class="price"><b>@(item.number*item.cost) </b></td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                                <tr>

                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                             .
                             .
                             .
```

but it dose not recognize Item1 above.(tuple.Item1.TypeCheck)
and when i send migrated model to view and fill it  , will tbl_Order and  tbl_purchase   fill?

Comment: By convention C# method names should be capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a view model with both types.

```
public class ViewModelX
{
    public myProject.Models.tbl_Order Order { get; set; }
    public myProject.Models.tbl_purchase Purchase { get; set; }
}
```

Then use that view model in the view.

```
@model ViewModelX
<label class="checkbox payment-method inline">
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Order.TypeCheck)remember me</label>
```

Comment: i did . but it dose not recognize Order in m => m.Order.TypeCheck.

Comment: i 'm updating my question . and put new according u'r advice.

Comment: Did you create the view model I described above and change the model type of your view to that view model?

Comment: a tuple is not the same as a dedicated ViewModel

Comment: @AndrewCounts  That is correct.  They are not strictly the same though are semantically and conceptually similar because a 2-tuple is simply a type encapsulating 2 child types which is analogous to the view model I posted.

Comment: hmm I see the change now, it appears you commented out the Tuple and added the ViewModel, can you show how you are filling the ViewModel in your controller?